# Prevent a user from login via SSH login as different user to server

Tags: linux, ssh, centos8

If a **userA** connects to a server via SSH is there a way to prevent **userA** from ssh'ing into any server as **userB** from the server he logged in?

```
ssh userA@serverN 
userA@serverN's password: *****

Last login: Wed Mar  3 14:41:47 2021 from 192.168.2.40
[userA@serverN ~]$ 
[userA@serverN ~]$ ssh userB@serverAny <-- Deny this to userA or prevent userA from ssh'ing as userB
```

Any way possible for CentOS8 or RHEL8 based machines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [sf] or maybe [unix.se]. Besides that, this question is pretty vague in its current form. It would be difficult to provide a useful example without knowing what the user _is_ allowed to do on the server and how thoroughly you want to prevent him from breaking the rules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First idea that comes to my mind is to make "ssh" a wrapper script which checks the parameters to enforce your rules and then exec the real ssh binary.

It may require other things like a chrooted environment to prevent access to the real ssh binary...